# Submit button not showing in second module in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two modules file1.py and file2.py. In file1.py i have created a class and a function with label and entry widgets. In file2.py, i inherit the class of file1.py and create a submit button in a function. So, when i click the submit button, the value entered in entry widget in file1.py should be displayed. But what i observe is, submit button is not dislayed and when i close the window, the entered value is displayed. I'm unable to understand this behavior, can anyone correct my mistake.

### file1.py

```
from Tkinter import *
top = Tk()


class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.func()


    def func(self):
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text = "LabelName")
        self.label.pack()

        self.x = StringVar()
        self.entry = Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.x)
        self.entry.pack()  

app = TestClass(master = top)
top.minsize(400, 400)
top.mainloop()
```

### file2.py

```
from file1 import *

class ImportClass(TestClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ImportClass,self).__init__(master=None)
        self.imp_func()

    def imp_func(self): 
        def get_func():
            print app.x.get()

        self.s = Button(self.frame, text="Submit", command=get_func())
        self.s.pack()


Im = ImportClass()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem, to get this to work you have to fix a few things:

First, you need to use your imported class as `app`, which has the submit button, to be still able to run just file1 you can check in file1.py the `__name__` whether it's `'__main__'` like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = TestClass(master = top)
    top.minsize(400, 400)
    top.mainloop()
```

Secondly, your function is not called because you call the function and give the result to `Button`, here you should just pass the function without calling it:

```
self.s = Button(self.frame, text="Submit", command=get_func())
```

in the function itself you **should not** use a global variable like `app`, because for example if you have multiple instances of the same class they would all depend on one instance and in the `TestClass` you have set `self.x` which is also accessible in `ImportClass` so you should replace the `print` statement with `print self.x.get()` instead of `print app.x.get()` to set the master from `ImportClass` to `top`. I also added `*args` and `**kwargs` to be passed on in the `__init__` method so all in all you get:

### file1.py

```
from Tkinter import *


class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.func()


    def func(self):
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text = "LabelName")
        self.label.pack()

        self.x = StringVar()
        self.entry = Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.x)
        self.entry.pack() 

 if __name__ == '__main__': 
    #just run if the file is called as main
    top = Tk()
    app = TestClass(master = top)
    top.minsize(400, 400)
    top.mainloop()
```

### and file2.py

```
from file1 import *
from Tkinter import *

class ImportClass(TestClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #passing all args and kwargs to super
        super(ImportClass,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.imp_func()

    def imp_func(self): 
        def get_func():
            print self.x.get()
            #using class property instead of global

        self.s = Button(self.frame, text="Submit", command=get_func)
        #pass function not it's return value which has been None
        self.s.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    top = Tk()
    app = ImportClass(master = top)
    #using the ImportClass to display the window
    top.minsize(400, 400)
    top.mainloop()
```

so this should work. Hopefully, this helps you to prevent further problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason you're having trouble is that *no lines will run* after `mainloop` until the `Tk` instance is closed or an event happened. When you `import file1`, `mainloop` is eventually run and then the GUI is waited to be closed in order to first define the `ImportClass` and then later to initialize an object for it.

Simply remove:

```
top.mainloop()
```

from `file1` and add:

```
top.mainloop()
```

to `file2` as the last line.

---

After which there's another issue, `command` option of a button expects a reference to a callable object, as opposed to an actual call. Replace:

```
self.s = Button(..., command=get_func())
```

with:

```
self.s = Button(..., command=get_func)
```

---

Also, note that I think your imports are in reverse order, obtain GUI objects *by* the module that has the `Tk` instance as opposed to vice-versa.